# How to write these equations and arrange it?

Tags: equations

[image]

I will try to write more equation under of them, but I cannot

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you a full code of what you tried?

Comment: Don’t just write `max` in math mode: use `\max` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Creating the equations is pretty straight forward.
I am using the `amsmath` package for the `align*` environment, which lets me align the equations easily.

Furthermore, I guess the small closing brace in the third line is a typo?!?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \max &= h \left( \frac{d(x, Ty) + d(y, Tx)}{2} \right) \\
       &= h \left( \frac{d(x, Ty)}{2} + \frac{d(y, Tx)}{2} \right) \\
       &\leq \max \left\{
          d(x, y), d(x, Tx), d(y, Ty),
          \frac{d(x, Tx)}{2} + \frac{h}{2} d(y, Tx) \right\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result from pdfLaTeX:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

If you want more than these three equations, just end the last equation line with `\\` and start out the next.  You can also have more equations like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a &= 2 + 2 \\
    &= 4 \\
  b &= \pi
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result from pdfLaTeX:

[image]